# passing array by reference recursive function

Tags: php

I need to get category names recursively. I can't pass array to recursive function.

```
function getCat($id, array &$cats) {
    global $db;
    $cc = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_articlecategories WHERE id=?");
    $cc->execute(array($id));
    $cat = $cc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $cats[] = $cat->title;
    if ($cat->nodeId != 0) { // top node
        getCat($cat->nodeId, $cats);
    } else {
        return implode(' => ', array_reverse($cats));
    }
}

var_dump(getCat(21));
```

Sample Data:

```
id | title | nodeId
1    Main         0
5    Electronics  1
21   TV's         5
```

Comment: In the if section you are missing `return` hence it won't return in that case

Comment: `array_reverse($cats)` is __not__ a variable

Comment: yes it is an array